# mutex lock in multi-tasking system

Tags: arm, mutex, xilinx, multitasking

I know it’s been written a lot about mutex implementation, however I couldn’t find any solution for my problem.

I am working on one core multi-task system ran from RTOS.

Task_1()  // lower priority preemptive task

Task_2()  // higher priority task

I am trying to implement mutex for locking the Uart communication port, however I am facing with the following problem:

Task_1 locks the mutex and starts sending a message over Uart port.
In meantime it’s been preempted (interrupted) by the higher priority Task_2 which also attempts to send data over UART.
Task_2, however can not lock the mutex since the task which is holding the mutex locked was interrupted and it can not unlock it. This blocks both Tasks run.

Is there any good solution to avoid or resolve this situation?
The goal is also not to corrupt the Uart data sent by Task_1.

Comment: You have encountered [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion). A comprehensive answer to this question may not be possible in the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: Firstly, Task_1 will regain control once Task_2 doesn't get the mutex. If this is not enough, you can disable interrupts, instead of mutex.

Comment: What does this have to do with arm or xilinx?

Comment: I am running on Xilinx Zynq ARM Cortex-A9 processor.